# Custom Animation of icons on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, adobe

I want to do a custom animation on the social icons on my website. For eg: I want to make the linkedin, facebook and insta icons behave like they are hanging on a cloth rope along with a clipper. I want them to animate only when hovered with a feel of clothes hanging in air. Looking for ideas how i can implement this? I understand i dont have a working example to show you guys but i am trying to get some ideas as to how to go about this. Very new to JS, CSS and Adobe. Looking for something like this-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uGuyOG68qQ

Instead of the clothes just want my social icons to hang in there.

Comment: try CSS: [transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: I belive the best way for you is to just follow the video as a guideline and change the "cloth" icons with your social icons

Comment: I believe Adobe after effects will help you out but its a costly software. you can try using fedesc suggestions. A good question btw.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen- How do i animate only on hover with the given example?

Comment: You can start from this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/01/02/clothesline-social-bookmarking/ and work your way by adding some animation.

Comment: @Crezzur - Really helpful!